# array_search recursive function php

Tags: php

I have this function which is supposed to generate random numbers and make sure they are not in the exceptions array, but I have this corner case:

It does not execute the while condition:

```
Exceptions Array
(
    [0] => 84
    [1] => 94
    [2] => 46

)
```

**print_r ouput** : *number generated is 46 we have a match number im going to return is 84*

so it does the first check correctly but not the recursive check, so it returns to me a duplicate value 84, is my while condition wrong?

```
function randWithout($from, $to, array $exceptions) {
    //sort($exceptions); // lets us use break; in the foreach reliably
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($exceptions);
    echo '</pre>';
    $number = mt_rand($from, $to); 
    print_r('number generated is' . $number);
    if(array_search($number,$exceptions) != FALSE) 
    {
        echo 'we have a match';
        do {

            $number = mt_rand($from, $to);

        } while(array_search($number,$exceptions) === FALSE);
    }
    print_r('number im going to return is'. $number);
    return $number;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm just blind, but I don't see any recursion in the above.  Could you point it out?

Comment: `while(array_search($number,$exceptions) === FALSE)` but 'im thinking i just need a `return $number` inside that if loop

Comment: Recursion is when a function calls itself.  That's not happening above.

Comment: whats with the `print_r` ? the code above does not work as is

Comment: theres nothing recursive. its an iteration. if is a statement not a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's what you should change it to:

```
$ex = [12,18,15];

for($i=0; $i<20;$i++) {
    print randWithout(10,20,$ex) . PHP_EOL;
}

function randWithout($from, $to, array $exceptions) {
    do {
        $number = mt_rand($from, $to);
    } while(in_array($number,$exceptions));

    return $number;
}
```

Just tested it and it works.

Comment: array_search returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise. So it should work fine, I tried in_array() same problem.

Answer (score 0):

changed to:

```
if(in_array($number,$exceptions) != FALSE) 
    {
        echo 'we have a match';
        do {

            $number = mt_rand($from, $to);

        } while(in_array($number,$exceptions));
    }
```

Removed the `== FALSE` clause from in_array, as it returns true if needle is found.